# Многопоточное асинхронное скачивание файлов с проверкой существования файла

Tags: python, многопоточность, изображения, асинхронность, производительность

Есть программа, которая по тегам находит посты. Затем по ним осуществляет скачивание изображений с полученных filepath внутри списка объектов Posts.

Проблема со скачиванием файлов в функциях download_media и _download_media. В том числе с проверкой существования файлов в папке, чтобы не качать файл повторно.

Программа скачивает их по одному, по очереди, не смотря на то, что должна разделить обработку массива **for post in Posts** и скачать файлы одновременно, ну или хотя бы в пределах количества ядер процессора. Когда постов мало, 90 изображений качаются минуту, не очень долго.

```
...
File already exists D:\ghd\img\artist imbi\40843394cbc7dde31b82dbbb6d817c651013475112a351dec7a07cb5bbe0e19d.jpg
File already exists D:\ghd\img\artist imbi\d3f1044c5879e688ef4d6d5b2356dae2058e3209b7b0261f017671c50a9ba8a6.jpg
it took: 50.14s
```

Если постов много, тогда очень долго. Не знаю как исправить эту ситуацию, улучшить программу в производительности в этой части.
Нужно решить 2 вопроса: *Как добиться параллельного скачивания файлов в многопоточном режиме* и *Проверка на существование файлов происходит медленно* в  `if os.path.exists(filepath)`
В терминал выводит по 2 записи в секунду. Перебор папки с большим количеством файлов занимает ну слишком долгое время, чтобы проверить, что есть, а что отсутствует и нужно скачать.

```
def main():
    start = time.perf_counter()
    print("Запущено: ", start)
    
    save_dir = 'D:/ghd/img/'
    positive_tags = ['artist:imbi']
    extra_tags = ['sarah_(the_last_of_us)']
    negative_tags = ['dragon_ball']
    # go to dir
    string_tag = ''.join(positive_tags)
    folder_tag = re.sub(r'[;,:\s]', ' ', string_tag)
    if not os.path.exists(save_dir + folder_tag):
        os.makedirs(save_dir + folder_tag)
    os.chdir(save_dir + folder_tag)
    print("Текущая директория изменилась на ", os.getcwd())
    # Gets all posts with the tags
    Posts = api.get_posts_with_tags(positive_tags, negative_tags, extra_tags)
    print("Мы получили посты")
    print("Начата загрузка тега ", positive_tags)
    threads = []
    for post in Posts:
        t = Thread(target=api.download_media, args=(post, Path.cwd(),))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"it took: {end - start:.2f}s")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Соответственно в модуле api.py есть вызываемые для этого функции

```
def download_media(post: Post, filepath: Path) -> List[str]:
    """Download all media on a post and save it.

    Args:
        post: The post to download.
        filepath: The file directory to save the media. The directory will be created if it doesn't
            already exist.

    Returns:
        The names of the images downloaded.

    """
    images_downloaded = []
    filepath.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    #print("Мы внутри downloadmedia")
    for media_meta_data in post.imageurls:
        filename = f'{media_meta_data.dataid}.{media_meta_data.type}'
        image_filepath = filepath.joinpath(filename)
        _download_media(media_meta_data.imageurl, image_filepath)
        images_downloaded.append(filename)
    #print("Мы закончили downloadmedia")
    return images_downloaded


def _download_media(image_url: str, filepath: Path):
    """Download an image and save it.

    Args:
        image_url: The image URL.
        filepath: The file directory to save the media. The directory will be created if it doesn't
            already exist.

    """
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Referer': 'https://nozomi.la/',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'
    }
    if os.path.exists(filepath):
        print('File already exists', filepath)
    else:
        print('File not exists %s', filepath)
        with requests.get(image_url, stream=True, headers=headers) as r:
            with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
                shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
        _LOGGER.debug('Image downloaded %s', filepath)
        print('File downloaded ', filepath)
```

На текущий момент программа реализована без асинхронности.
Полный код программы [GitHub](https://github.com/SolitarySpiral/python-image-dowloader)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149552/discussion-on-question-by-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Для асинхронной реализации в первую очередь нужно синхронный requests заменить на httpx (асинхронный вариант кода, естественно) или aiohttp. А дальше уже все последовательные ожидания менять на параллельные через asyncio.gather.

Comment: @insolor После последней правки боюсь добавлять ещё асинхронность. Да и без неё вроде ничего. Уже начинаю путаться во всех этих терминах. Вложенность функций друг в друга ещё сильнее путает втыкая в них параллели и ожидания. runner -> get_urls_list, download_file. get_urls_list ->_get_post_urls->_get_post_ids->requests.get. download_file->requests.get. Если что-то править, желательно готовый код для каждой из них. А то сломается снова, как было до этого =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Требуемое решение: асинхронность, проверка существования файлов.
(с асинхронным подходом многопоточность уже не нужна) расположено в полном коде программы [Git](https://github.com/SolitarySpiral/python-image-dowloader)

Для ограничения работы программы, чтобы не убить сервера запросами - используются семафоры из того же asyncio. Для разных АПИ свое количество. `semaphoreNozomi = asyncio.Semaphore(20)`

Общий код, в целом, рукожопый, ООП вышло из чата, но хотя бы работает. Не слишком ущербно для проекта в 1 лицо новичка.